# Function or formula that returns a value based on three conditions

Tags: excel, indexing, match, lookup

I'm at a dead end on this, after numerous searches, trials and failures, and I hope someone knows the solution to this.

I have a list of item ID's where each ID also has a date-stamp. It looks like this;

[image]

In column C I want a formula or function that looks through a list of ID's that also includes a StartDate and an ExpireDate, as well as a concatenation of the ID itself(LookUp Table column B), the value of StartDate and the value of ExpireDate, creating a new ID that I later on can make a VLOOKUP on to return the price on a specific date in a specific period.

[image]

For this I need the concatenation value in LookUp Table column B returned to the respective cells in column C in the DataTable, if the ID is found, AND if the Date in the DataTable is larger than the ID's StartDate in the LookUp Table AND smaller than the ExpireDate in the LookUp Table. In short I am working with ID's that in fact always remains the same, but the LookUp Table contains many versions of the same ID, but with different prices depending on the period.

I tried misc. lookups as well as different INDEX, MATCH etc, but nothing worked for me.
I hope someone can assist me in this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's called a "Helper Column": https://exceljet.net/glossary/helper-column

Comment: can you share how the " ..a concatenation of the ID itself(LookUp Table column B), the value of StartDate and the value of ExpireDate.. " output looks like..? say.. for SEAFCLBUDDFW5, ( for both date ) .

Comment: Thanks HackSlash - helper columns combined with the below formula worked like a charm. Its a bit slow though, but okay..

Comment: =LOOKUP(2;1/(I:I<=B2)/(J:J>=B2);K:K)